# What cable is needed for Sennheiser ME66/K6 and Olympus LS-12

Tags: cable, sennheiser

I`m planning to buy a Sennheiser ME66/K6 mic set and a recorder (possibly Olympys LS-12). What is the cable I would need to connect the mic set to the recorder?

Comment: Are you going to use a single ME66? And do you want to record to one channel, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ME66 is a mono microphone, and the Olympus records in stereo.

- Record on one channel: XLR to 3.5mm mono jack cable.
- Record one microphone to both channels (not recommended): XLR->Jack where the XLR positive terminal is connected to both tip and ring of the 3.5 mm jack.